# Scalar fields proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, laplacian

[image: ra]

How to prove that for every two scalar fields $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$ the identity above holds true?

I guess it says the Laplacian of the dot product of two scalar fields equals the Laplacian of each field times the other field plus the gradient of each field times the gradient of the other field?

Comment: What do **you** mean by the "dot product" of two scalars?

Comment: You're right it cant be a dot product.....if it's a SCALAR field after all....regular multiplication then?

Comment: What identity? Please include all important parts of your question as text instead of pasting pictures of them. Your question is incomprehensible without that image, so is inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries. You’ve got a fair amount of reputation already, so should know this, but if not, see [this part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10992/265466) of “How to ask a good question.”

Answer (score 1):

We have: $(uv)_x=u_xv+uv_x,$ hence

$$(uv)_{xx}=u_{xx}v+2u_xv_x+v_{xx}u.$$

Now compute $(uv)_{yy}$ and $(uv)_{zz}$ and add.